# Can't access history after Plastic upgrade

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

My project recently got upgraded to plastic SCM from Unity Collab. I need to go back to one of the previous commits from collab but I'm not able to do so as Plastic shows nothing in the history of the project.

[Plastic History Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3JwQ.png)

Whereas you can see the previous commits in Collab window-
[Collab History Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKKVD.png)

Apart from this a lot of errors were thrown in the beginning. I fixed them by clearing the cache folder and reimporting everything which updated the packages.

[Errors thrown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y9YP.png)

How to access the history of the project using Plastic?

Answer (score 0):

This are completely different systems with independent repos, the history of unity collab cannot be shared with plastic SCM. If your unity collab repo its still on the cloud you could try and checkout a past commit there through the unity collab interface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).